# Linked List insertion/deletion

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

```
                   // ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next; 
};
Node* head = NULL;
int size;
Node* tail = NULL;

void printLinkedList() {
    Node *search = head;
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "linkedlist is empty" << endl;
    }
    else { 
        while (search != NULL){
            cout << search->data << endl;
            search = search->next;
        }
    }
}
int sizeLinkedList() {
    size = 1;
    Node* current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
        size = size + 1;
        }
    cout << size << endl;
    return size;
}

Node *getNode(int position){
    Node *current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i<position; i++)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

    return current;
}
void appendNode(int n) {
    Node *newNode = new Node; //creating new node
    newNode->data = n;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    else {
        Node *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;

    }
    }

void insertNode(int n, int position) {
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = n;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    int size = sizeLinkedList();
    if (position = 0){
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else{
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
    }

    else if (position == size) {
        appendNode(n);
    }

    else {
        Node *prevNode = getNode(position-1);
        Node *nextNode = getNode(position);
        prevNode->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = nextNode;

            }

        }


void deleteNode(int position) {
    Node *currentNode;

    int size = sizeLinkedList();
    if (size == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (position == 0) {
        currentNode = head->next;
        head = currentNode;
    }
    else if (position == size-1) {
        getNode(position - 1)->next = NULL;
        delete getNode(position);

            }
    else {
        getNode(position - 1)->next = getNode(position+1);
        delete getNode(position);
    }
        }




//making a dynamic array only via pointers in VC++
    void makeArray() {
    int* m = NULL;
    int n;
    cout << "how many entries are there?"<<endl;
    cin >> n;
    m = new int[n];
    int temp;
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        cout << "enter item:"<< x+1<< endl;
        cin >> temp;
        *(m + x) = temp;
    } 
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        cout << x+1 + ":" << "There is item: "<<*(m+x) << endl;

    }
    delete[]m;
}
int main() {
    int x;
    //makeArray();
    appendNode(1);
    appendNode(2);
    appendNode(32);
    appendNode(55);
    appendNode(66);
    //insertNode(2, 0);
    printLinkedList();
    deleteNode(3);
    printLinkedList();
    sizeLinkedList();
    cin >> x;

}
```

Im just trying to code a Linked List with a couple of functions for practice
My Delete function, the last else statement isnt working, and logically I cant figure out why,
as for my insert function none of the statements are working, not even at head or position 0. However appending items, returning size, printing the list, deleting the first and last elements works.

thanks!

Comment: `if (position = 0)` should be `if (position == 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `sizeLinkedList` won't work correctly if the list is empty (it cannot return 0)
2. you are using `size` as different variables at different scopes (at main scope, and within `deleteNode`).  This is pretty confusing although not strictly wrong.
3. in `deleteNode`, this sequence won't work:

   ```
   else if (position == size-1) {
     getNode(position - 1)->next = NULL;
     delete getNode(position);
     }
   ```

   setting the `next` pointer on the node prior to `position` to NULL will interfere with the attempt to `getNode(position)` in the very next line, because it traverses the list based on `next`.  The fix is to reverse these two lines.
4. Likewise, your last sequence in `deleteNode` won't work for a similar reason, because you are modifying the next pointers:

   ```
   else {
     getNode(position - 1)->next = getNode(position+1);
     delete getNode(position);  // this list traversal will skip the node to delete!
     }
   ```

   the solution here is like this:

   ```
   else {
     currentNode = getNode(position);
     getNode(position - 1)->next = getNode(position+1);
     delete currentNode;
     }
   ```
5. I've also re-written the `insertNode` function incorporating the comment provided by @0x499602D2 .

Here's a modified version of your code that has your current sequence in `main` fixed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next; 
};
Node* head = NULL;
int size = 0;
Node* tail = NULL;

void printLinkedList() {
    Node *search = head;
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "linkedlist is empty" << endl;
    }
    else { 
        while (search != NULL){
            cout << search->data << endl;
            search = search->next;
        }
    }
}
int sizeLinkedList() {
    size = 0;
    if (head->next != NULL){
      size = 1;
      Node* current = head;
      while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
        size = size + 1;
        }
      }
    cout << size << endl;
    return size;
}

Node *getNode(int position){
    Node *current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i<position; i++)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

    return current;
}
void appendNode(int n) {
    Node *newNode = new Node; //creating new node
    newNode->data = n;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    size++;
    if (head == NULL)
        {
        head = newNode;
        return;
        }
    else {
        Node *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
            }
        current->next = newNode;
        }
    }

void insertNode(int n, int position) {
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = n;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (position == 0){
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
    }

    else if (position == sizeLinkedList()) {
        appendNode(n);
    }

    else {
        Node *prevNode = getNode(position-1);
        Node *nextNode = getNode(position);
        prevNode->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = nextNode;
        }
    }


void deleteNode(int position) {
    Node *currentNode;

    int my_size = sizeLinkedList();
    if ((my_size == 0) || (position > my_size)) {
        return;
        }
    if (position == 0) {
        currentNode = head->next;
        head = currentNode;
        }
    else if (position == size-1) {
        delete getNode(position);
        getNode(position - 1)->next = NULL;
        }
    else {
        currentNode = getNode(position);
        getNode(position - 1)->next = getNode(position+1);
        delete currentNode;
        }
    }




//making a dynamic array only via pointers in VC++
    void makeArray() {
    int* m = NULL;
    int n;
    cout << "how many entries are there?"<<endl;
    cin >> n;
    m = new int[n];
    int temp;
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        cout << "enter item:"<< x+1<< endl;
        cin >> temp;
        *(m + x) = temp;
    } 
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        cout << x+1 + ":" << "There is item: "<<*(m+x) << endl;

    }
    delete[]m;
}
int main() {
    int x;
    //makeArray();
    appendNode(1);
    appendNode(2);
    appendNode(32);
    appendNode(55);
    appendNode(66);
    insertNode(2, 0);
    printLinkedList();
    deleteNode(3);
    printLinkedList();
    sizeLinkedList();
}
```

Comment: You missed `if (position = 0)` as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Fixed now.  My previous update had not un-commented `insertNode` in `main` yet, matching OP's code, and `insertNode` was not fixed.  It seems to be working for OP's test case now.